# Realm Object not visible after update

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, realm

I using Realm on my Xamarin app for iOS

I have model

```
 public class Filter: RealmObject
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

But I have error

> /Users/evhenijsuhomlyn/Documents/GitHub/Xplorpal_ios/xplorpal.core/RealmEntities/Location.cs(28,28): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RealmObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (xplorpal.core)

But I installed Realm nuget. Version 4.1.0

How I can fix this?

Comment: did you resolve it ?

Comment: @Hunt Yes, just downgrade package to previous version